# What is the best way to customize fonts or colors using storyboards?

Tags: ios, storyboard

How to customize the fonts and colors in a project with storyboards without having to change it everytime in the storyboards. Is there any way that I can specify some variables in the storyboard which could be changed just once?.

Problem : 
Designers keep changing the fonts and colors according to whatever looks good, or change the theme color of the whole app.

One of the solutions is to create IBOutlets of views and assign them via code(themeColor, tableViewFillColor, headingFont, subHeadingFont, etc.) but I think this is a very lengthy process.

Currently I am assigning everything in the storyboard. Is there any way that I can somehow drop some object in a storyboard which I can assign it everywhere else needed? Any other solutions if possible?

Comment: i really like this question. I don't know what is the best approach of this kind of situation, but I do same thing you do but, as you said, it's a long process.

Comment: still someone downvoted the question :-/. Please let me know if there is any clarity required

Comment: I upvoted your question but it still doesnt show xd

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 6 you can create `IBDesignable` and `IBInspectable` of these properties create `IBDesignable` and `IBInspectable`outlet of these properties like (themeColor, tableViewFillColor, headingFont, subHeadingFont, etc.)

Below is link i have shared,and there are lot of tutorial in Google to find which shows how to use it

http://www.appcoda.com/ibdesignable-ibinspectable-tutorial/

http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Comment: IBInspectable will only create variables which would allow me to assign colors using storyboards. But the problem is that I will still have to put it everywhere in the code.
Here one thing is done great, that the colors are predefined in the code and it creates variables in the storyboard with those names. So is there any way that I could define those variables as colors in nib itself, so that wheneever I change those predefined values , the storyboard could directly reflect those changes?
P.S. I have worked with ibdesignables, still figuring out the depth at which these could be used

Comment: Using IBDesignable, the easiest method I can see is to create subclass of UIButton, UILabel or any other related classes and predefine these properties either as ibdesignables so that these could be visible in storyboard, or just normal properties. But somehow I am not really liking the idea of creating different -2 subclasses for different -2 colors or different fonts

Comment: Yes tats da way it is done mostly,u have to subclass it create outlets and den u can modify these properties on da go.der are many example.i will share u tomorw

Comment: You mean subclasses like RedColorUILabel, BlueColoredLabel, ThemeColoredLabel right? Or is there any way that I can create just one CustomColoredUILabel which I can use everywhere? 
P.S. if I could do something like the latter option, that would be awesome!

Comment: Is there any way I can create a list using IBInspectable? Like the UITableViewCell has while setting style with options Custom, Basic, Right Detail, Left Detail? If this is possible then it would open up some more options as well

Comment: i have edited again, der is also `IBInspectable` also where u can define runtime properties.check the link i shared and google it to find in depth

Comment: I dont think it actually matters if you define any class as `IBDesignable` or not, its the `IBInspectable` which actually makes the link. `IBDesignable` is just to see the changes in the interface builder. But even if you don't write any class as `IBDesignable` the end result would still be the same.